# I am having a problem with understanding this python code

Tags: python

I want to learn Python and I took a test. I the test I came across this code and I needed to get it's output.

I put the correct answer which was 6, but I didn't understand the code, I just put it in an online python compiler!

Why does this code output a `6`?

```py
def func(x):
    res = 0
    for i in range(x):
        res += i
    return res

print(func(4))
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly are you confused by? Any python tutorial will go over all the concepts being used here.

Comment: the functionality will change according to `x` type (`string`, `int`, `char`, `float`)

Answer (score 3):

I thing this will solve your problem buddy

```
def func(x):
    res = 0

    for i in range(x):
        print "x",i
        print "res",res
        res += i
        print "res out", res
    return res
print(func(4))
```

result:

```
x 0
res 0
res out 0
x 1
res 0
res out 1
x 2
res 1
res out 3
x 3
res 3
res out 6
6
```

Answer (score 1):

you're passing number `4` as variable `x` into the function and printing the result in the end.

in the for loop, `i` is a temporary variable representing each number in range `0` to `4`.

so the steps in the code look like this

```
for 0 in range 0 to 4
```

add `0` to `variable res` = `0 + 0 = 0`

now res = 0

next step/loop for `1` in range `0 to 4`

add `1` to `variable res` = `0 + 1 = 1`

now `res = 1`

next step/loop for `2` in range `0 to 4`

add `2` to `variable res` = `1 + 2 = 3`

now `res = 3`

next step/loop for `3` in range `0 to 4`

add `3` to `variable res` = `3 + 3 = 6`

now `res = 6`

and the loop is done, giving you the result 6

Answer (score 1):

You assign the value of i to the res and then res value is added to the value of i and your output is assign to the value of res that is when x=3, res become 3 and added with the value 3 is equal to 6 boom

def is used to define function and range means from start to the end point you want so in your case you passed 4 as variable x into your function that means your loop start with the value of 0 and end when value is 4.